# org.apache.spark#spark-streaming_2.11_2.10;2.3.1: not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework

Hello I am new to play framework. 
In build.sbt I tried to add spark streaming dependency of scala 2.11 but it can not found.

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.3.1" % "provided"
```

It gives me error 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOZga.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.1" % "provided"
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11/2.3.1 - choose sbt tab